# Argument of type '(req: Request, res: IResponse, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams' with express.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm creating a route handler and I want to add it in my routes:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

interface IResponse extends Response {
  error: (code: number, message: string) => Response;
  success: (code: number, message: string, result: any) => Response
}
const routeHandler = (req: Request, res: IResponse, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.error = (statusCode: number, errorMessage: string) => res.status(statusCode).json(errorMessage);
  res.success = (statusCode: number, message: string, result: any) => res.status(statusCode).json({
    message,
    result
  });
  return next();
};

export default routeHandler;
```

when I added this handler to the routes index file:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import routeHandler from "../utils/helpers";

const routes = Router();
routes.use(routeHandler);

export default routes;
```

I got this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: IResponse, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
      Type '(req: Request, res: IResponse, next: NextFunction) => void' is missing the following properties from type '(string | RegExp)[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(55, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Express does not know anything about your interface `IResponse`. So the method cannot match.

To achieve your idea, use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface Response {
        error: (code: number, message: string) => Response;
        success: (code: number, message: string, result: any) => Response
    }
}

const routeHandler = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.error = (statusCode: number, errorMessage: string) => res.status(statusCode).json(errorMessage);
    res.success = (statusCode: number, message: string, result: any) => res.status(statusCode).json({
        message,
        result
    });
    return next();
};

export default routeHandler;
```

Comment: Why doesn't it know about it? His `IResponse` extends `Response`

Comment: routes.use(...) expect Response, not IResponse. This like developers of Express Router does not know anything about IResponse. But IResponse requires to fields "error" and "success". So, developers of Express Router should pass this field, but they are don't

Comment: after trying a lot of solutions this helped me, thanks, +1

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that I was using the native `Request`, `Response`, and `NextFunction` interfaces from Node.js (no imports), rather than the interfaces from `express`:

Before

```
const auth = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // middleware stuff

  next();
};
```

After

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

const auth = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // middleware stuff

  next();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i'm facing the same issue, for me the fix is to set explicitly setting the type as `RequestHandler`

```
import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express';

export interface Request extends ExpressRequest {
  id: string;
}
```

requestId Handler.ts

```
import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { Request } from '../../interfaces/Request';

export const requestIdHandler = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.id = nanoid() as string;
  res.setHeader('X-Request-Id', req.id);
  next();
};
```

in App.ts

```
 app.use(requestIdHandler as express.RequestHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
interface IResponse extends Response {
  error?: (code: number, message: string) => Response;
  success?: (code: number, message: string, result: any) => Response
}
```